# My application crashes because according to the garbage collector, only 4% heap memory is remaining... How do I prevent this?

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, garbage-collection

I'm using bitmaps in my android application and open GLES 2.0 to render them. 
  The app crashes with the log GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 4% free 12240K/12640K.My objective is to render bitmaps from the gallery folder of my phone/tablet. All that works fine. I collect all the texture (image) details (the place on my screen where it has to be rendered and the name of the image from textures = MyApplication.getTextures(); 
textures is a continuously GROWING arraylist. Hence, in my onDrawFrame, I'm drawing all the textures in each frame. Note that the bitmaps are coming from the gallery and not the resource folder.
This is the code:

```
package com.example.hmi_abp;


import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;`
import java.nio.ShortBuffer;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;`
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

import com.example.rendering.TextureHelper;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES20;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView.Renderer;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
import android.opengl.Matrix;

public class GLRenderer implements Renderer {

// Our matrices
private final float[] mtrxProjection = new float[16];
private final float[] mtrxView = new float[16];
private final float[] mtrxProjectionAndView = new float[16];

// Geometric variables
public static float vertices[][];
public static short indices[][];
public FloatBuffer vertexBuffer[];
public ShortBuffer drawListBuffer[];
public static float uvs[][];
public FloatBuffer uvBuffer[];
private final Context mActivityContext;




// Our screenresolution
float   mScreenWidth = 1280;
float   mScreenHeight = 768;

// Misc
Context mContext;
int mProgram;
int number;
private ArrayList<TextureProperties> textures;
private int[] mTextureDataHandle;

public GLRenderer(Context c)
{
    mActivityContext = c;

}

public void onPause()
{
    /* Do stuff to pause the renderer */
}
public void onResume()
{



}

@Override
public synchronized void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {


    textures=MyApplication.getTextures();



    number = textures.size();

    System.out.println("number"+ number);

    mTextureDataHandle = new int[number];
    vertices=new float[number][12];
    uvs=new float[number][8];
    indices=new short [number][6];
    vertexBuffer = new FloatBuffer[number];
    drawListBuffer= new ShortBuffer[number];
    uvBuffer=new FloatBuffer[number];

      int k=0,h,w;
        for(;k<number;k++)
        {

            Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(textures.get(k).name);

            h=bitmap.getHeight();
            w=bitmap.getWidth();
                                setUpBuffers(k,h,w);

              Render(mtrxProjectionAndView,k);
        }



}

private synchronized void Render(float[] m, int k) {


                mTextureDataHandle[k] = 
TextureHelper.loadTexture(mActivityContext,textures.get(k).name);

            // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
int mPositionHandle=GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image,"vPosition");

            // Enable generic vertex attribute array
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

            // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(mPositionHandle, 3,
                                         GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                                         0, vertexBuffer[k]);

            // Get handle to texture coordinates location
            int mTexCoordLoc = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image,      "a_texCoord" );

            // Enable generic vertex attribute array
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray ( mTexCoordLoc );

            // Prepare the texturecoordinates
            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer ( mTexCoordLoc, 2, GLES20.GL_FLOAT,
                    false,
                    0, uvBuffer[k]);

            // Get handle to shape's transformation matrix
            int mtrxhandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "uMVPMatrix");

            // Apply the projection and view transformation
            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mtrxhandle, 1, false, mtrxProjectionAndView, 0);

            // Get handle to textures locations
            int mSamplerLoc = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation (riGraphicTools.sp_Image, "s_texture" );

            // Set the sampler texture unit to 0, where we have saved the texture.
            GLES20.glUniform1i ( mSamplerLoc, 0);
        //    System.out.println(k);
            // Draw the triangle
            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, indices[k].length,
                    GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, drawListBuffer[k]);

            // Disable vertex array
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mTexCoordLoc);

}

@Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {

    // We need to know the current width and height.
    mScreenWidth = width;
    mScreenHeight = height;

    // Redo the Viewport, making it fullscreen.
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, (int)mScreenWidth, (int)mScreenHeight);

    // Clear our matrices
    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
    {
        mtrxProjection[i] = 0.0f;
        mtrxView[i] = 0.0f;
        mtrxProjectionAndView[i] = 0.0f;
    }

    // Setup our screen width and height for normal sprite translation.
    Matrix.orthoM(mtrxProjection, 0, 0f, mScreenWidth, 0.0f, mScreenHeight, 0, 50);

    // Set the camera position (View matrix)
    Matrix.setLookAtM(mtrxView, 0, 0f, 0f, 1f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Calculate the projection and view transformation
    Matrix.multiplyMM(mtrxProjectionAndView, 0, mtrxProjection, 0, mtrxView, 0);

   }
   @Override
  public synchronized void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {




    // Set the clear color to black
   GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1);

    // Create the shaders, solid color
    int vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_SolidColor);
    int fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_SolidColor);

    riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_SolidColor);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables

    // Create the shaders, images
    vertexShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, riGraphicTools.vs_Image);
    fragmentShader = riGraphicTools.loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, riGraphicTools.fs_Image);

    riGraphicTools.sp_Image = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL ES Program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
    GLES20.glAttachShader(riGraphicTools.sp_Image, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);                  // creates OpenGL ES program executables

    // Set our shader programm
    GLES20.glUseProgram(riGraphicTools.sp_Image);








}

public synchronized void setUpBuffers(int k, int h, int w)
{


     // We have to create the vertices of our triangle.
    vertices[k] = new float[number*12];

        vertices[k][0]= textures.get(k).xPos;
        vertices[k][1]= textures.get(k).yPos;
        vertices[k][2]= 0.0f;
        vertices[k][3]= textures.get(k).xPos;
        vertices[k][4]= textures.get(k).yPos-h;
        vertices[k][5]= 0.0f;
        vertices[k][6]= textures.get(k).xPos+w;
        vertices[k][7]= textures.get(k).yPos-h;
        vertices[k][8]= 0.0f;
        vertices[k][9]= textures.get(k).xPos+w;
        vertices[k][10]= textures.get(k).yPos;
        vertices[k][11]= 0.0f;




    // The vertex buffer.
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertices[k].length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer[k] = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer[k].put(vertices[k]);
    vertexBuffer[k].position(0);

    indices[k] = new short[number*6];


        indices[k][0]   = 0;//(short) (k*4);
        indices[k][1] = 1;//(short) (k*4+1);
        indices[k][2] = 2;//(short) (k*4+2);
        indices[k][3] = 0;//(short) (k*4);
        indices[k][4] = 2;//(short) (k*4+2);
        indices[k][5] = 3;//(short) (k*4+3);

    // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
    ByteBuffer dlb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices[k].length * 2);
    dlb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    drawListBuffer[k] = dlb.asShortBuffer();
    drawListBuffer[k].put(indices[k]);
    drawListBuffer[k].position(0);




    // Create our UV coordinates.
    uvs[k] = new float[number*8];


            uvs[k][0]=0.0f;
            uvs[k][1]=0.0f;
            uvs[k][2]=0.0f;
            uvs[k][3]=1.0f;
            uvs[k][4]=1.0f;
            uvs[k][5]=1.0f;
            uvs[k][6]=1.0f;
            uvs[k][7]=0.0f;


    // The texture buffer
    ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(uvs[k].length * 4);
    bb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    uvBuffer[k] = bb2.asFloatBuffer();
    uvBuffer[k].put(uvs[k]);
    uvBuffer[k].position(0);


}

 }
```

Comment: looks like you missed calling `bitmap.recycle()` after dealing with the bitmap in line `Bitmap bitmap =BitmapFactory.decodeFile(textures.get(k).name);`.. this is eating up the heap space as nothing is getting released...

Comment: I'm doing that in a method called loadTextures.

Comment: I'm doing it here
TextureHelper.loadTexture(mActivityContext,textures.get(k).name);

Comment: ensure that the method is called after each bitmap is processed, based on what you mentioned in response to @Hamad, it looks like you are not releasing these resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `android:largeHeap="true"` in manifest file to request a larger heap size, but this will not work on any pre Honeycomb devices. On pre 2.3 devices, you can use the VMRuntime class, but this will not work on Gingerbread and above.

The only way to have as large a limit as possible is to do memory intensive tasks via the NDK, as the NDK does not impose memory limits like the SDK.

Alternatively, you can use these approaches:

[memory-out-of-error](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/08/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error.html)

[Memory Leak and Out of memory Error using List,LinkedList and HashMap](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/08/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error_29.html)

[Memory Leak and Out of memory Error using LRU Cache](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.ro/2013/09/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error.html)

[Memory Leak and Out of memory Error using Disk LRU Cache](http://www.shaikhhamadali.blogspot.com/2013/09/memory-leak-and-out-of-memory-error_3.html)

Comment: According to the DDMS, the main portion of the GC are the bitmaps.